# Question concerning weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

So here is my problem,

I want to show the following,

Let $X$ be a normed $\mathbb K$-Vectorspace.

And let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X$ be such that it converges weakly to some $x\in X$.

Then,

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k\rightharpoonup x\;,n\rightarrow\infty$$
i.e the sum also converges weakly to $x$.

I think by linearity it is sufficent to show that if $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges weakly to $0$ then the some does.

After a couple attempts trying to bound $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(x_k)$ for some arbitrary $f\in X^*$ I gave up.

So I wanted to ask if someone wants to give me hint how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know the corresponding result for real or complex sequences?

Comment: Yes! and I just see that it works also for the problem above. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Tomas could you be a little more precise please? Are you thinking about the LLN? I don't see the right way..

Comment: @sky90 The convergence follows from the cesaro mean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_mean

Comment: very smart argument ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of complex numbers converges to some $a$, then so does the sequence $(n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^na_j)_{n\geqslant 1}$.

For a fixed linear continuous functional, use this result with $a_k:=\langle f,x_k\rangle_{X',X}$.

Not completely related, but if $X$ was a Hilbert space, then we could extract a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_k$ of $(x_k)_k$ such that $(N^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^Nx_{n_j})_N$ converges *strongly* to $x$.